# Can't disable bootstrap button after complete

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

It's pretty simple:  after calling bootstrap button('complete') on an element el,

```
el.attr('disabled', 'disabled');​
```

and

```
el.addClass('disabled');​
```

have no effect

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2732/

This is what I expect (jsfiddle of it working with 'loading'): http://jsfiddle.net/xgKZd/

Comment: I'm not sure if I've got your point, you wanna change the css to disable after clicked? It is?!

Comment: Isn't it prohibited to change attributes like `disabled` of form controls through the DOM due to security reasons?

Comment: Yes I want the state to be disabled after the button reaches complete state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be merely a timing problem : if you "wait" before setting the `disabled` class and attribute, it works : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/D2RLR/2736/)

The plugin uses a timeout of 0 (check the source for more info) but it seems to "take" more time. Just add some delay or do the button effect yourself so that you can control the order of actions.

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#bton').button('complete'); }, 2000);

setTimeout(function() { $('#bton').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled'); }, 4000);
```

Comment: @sanon I don't know enough about JS. It must depends on the engine execution behavior.

Comment: Instead of 2000 (2 ms), enter a smaller value: 1 worked for me, and the human eye can't see any state change since it's so fast... But without the timeout, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same problem and wanted to share an alternative solution. You can change the loading-text data atrribute value. So if you have a button:

`<button id='myButton' data-loading-text="Loading..." type="submit">Save</button>`

And you initially do something and want to show the "Loading..." message

```
$('#myButton').button('loading');
```

Then when you're all done, you can do something like this:

```
$('#myButton').data('loading-text','Done!').button('loading');
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sherbrow is right but you don't need to wait 2 seconds to disable button. Because `.button`'s setState method is juggling with classes using setTimeout (checkout [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/js/bootstrap-button.js#L46)) you just have to do similar eg.:

```
var $btn = $('#btn');
$btn.button('complete');
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled'); 
}, 0);
```